# Index/matching based on two columns in R, is it possible?

Tags: r

I have the following "index" list that contains the name of six types of cars and their ID associated (DF1).

```
DF1 = structure(list(Car = c("Toyota", "Mitsubishi", "Audi", 
"Merecedes", "Ford", "Fiat"), ID = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Car", 
"ID"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then I have this list of various information (DF2).

```
DF2 = structure(list(City = c("New York City", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Miami", "Dallas", "Atlanta"), `2005` = c("", "", "", 
"Mercedes, Mitsubishi", "Ford", ""), `2006` = c("", 
"", "", "Ford", "Audi", ""), `2007` = c("Toyota", 
"", "Toyota", "", "Fiat, Audi, Audi", ""
), `2008` = c("Fiat", "", "", "Mitsubishi, Merecedes, Fiat, Mitsubishi", 
"Audi, Fiat, Merecedes", ""), `2009` = c("Fiat", 
"", "", "Audi, Toyota", "Toyota, Audi, Fiat", 
""), `2010` = c("", "", "", "Toyota, Merecedes, Merecedes, Audi, Mitsubishi", 
"", ""), `2011` = c("", "", "", "", "Toyota", ""), `2012` = c("", 
"", "", "Merecedes, Ford, Merecedes, Toyota", "Toyota", 
"Fiat"), `2013` = c("Fiat", "", "Toyota", "", "", 
""), `2014` = c("", "", "Fiat, Mitsubishi", "", "Mitsubishi, Audi, Toyota, Merecedes, Toyota, Mitsubishi, Fiat, Mitsubishi, Fiat", 
""), `2015` = c("", "", "Toyota", "", "Toyota, Merecedes", 
""), `2016` = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), `Contact` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), `Time` = c("2011", "2015", "2015", "2006, 2006, 2005, 2005, 2007", 
"2014, 2011", "2007"), Cut = c("2011", "2015", "2015", "2005", 
"2011", "2007")), .Names = c("City", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", 
"2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", 
"Contact", "Time", "Cut"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Columns 2 through 13 contain the name of the different cars. what I'd like R to do is to simply replace those names with the IDs from the "index" list above.

I have tried to use the replace `function` such as this:

```
replace(DF2, DF1$Car, DF2$ID)
```

But this doesn't seem to quite work. I'm open for other suggestions if `replace` is not the best solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a method using the `tidyverse` suite of packages.  `gather` and `spread` function similar to `reshape` in base.  The actual replacement is done using the `match` function, but we need to split up the list of cars by ", " first using `str_split`, do the replacement, then paste it all back together.

```
DF2 %>%
  gather(year, cars, `2005`:`2016`) %>%
  mutate(year, cars_id = map_chr(str_split(cars, ", "), ~ if(length(.x > 0)) paste(unique(DF1$ID[match(.x, DF1$Car)]), collapse = ", ") else "")) %>%
  select(-cars) %>%
  spread(year, cars_id)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked well! Let's say I was only interested in unique IDs, so if one year and city has a list of IDs such as `1, 1, 2` and I'm interested in making it remove duplicates so it only outputs `1, 2`, would it be possible in this code? I've tried adding a `unique` function outside the `paste` function in your code, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: it wouldn't - the output of `paste` is a single element.  I'll modify the code in a way that will work.

Answer (score 0):

And here is a method in base using `apply` and `gsub`

```
DF2m <- as.matrix(DF2)

apply(DF1, 1, function(x) {
  DF2m <<- gsub(x[1], x[2], DF2m)
})

DF2new <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(DF2m, nrow=nrow(DF2)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: This solution has the annoying "side effect" of turning all the variables into factors.

Comment: Good point, I edited to explicitly set the `stringsAsFactors` argument, which in this case does return the original types provided. If type preservation was an issue some indexing would be required.

Answer (score 0):

```
rep_carn_wid <- function(x, lo = DF1) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(lo)) {
    x <- gsub(lo[i, 1], lo[i, 2], x)
  }
  x
}

DF2[2:13] <- lapply(DF2[2:13],  rep_carn_wid)
```